# Can't ping in Bash on Windows

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

When I try to run:

```
ping www.google.com
```

I get the following error:

```
ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied
```

Running with `sudo` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `Why does the ping command require bash to be started with admin privileges? This is a known issue that has to due with differences between the way the Linux and the Windows kernel handle the ICMP request that makes ping possible. We plan to address this in future releases.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq#why-does-the-ping-command-require-bash-to-be-started-with-admin-privileges

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update:** This issue has been fixed since the *Windows 10 Creators Update* (April 2017). Bash on Windows no longer requires administrator rights to execute the ping command.

"The Windows TCP/IP stack requires admin privileges to open RAW sockets for security measures" [[source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/18)]. See [MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx). This only applies to low-level network protocols such as ICMP used by `ping`.

Running your "Bash on Windows" shell as administrator should allow the ping command to work. Simply right-click it's shortcut and select the option:

[image: Select 'run as administrator' for Bash start menu shortcut]

This will only work for the single session opened with these rights.

If other commands also can't connect to the internet (e.g. `apt-get`, `wget`) then you might also need to look at [Internet access not working in Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1066272/internet-access-not-working-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux).

Comment: this has been fixed recently - some insider builds don't need to run as admin to have ping and ping6 working

Comment: it's funny that you are already root without running as administrator, but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work before because as pointed out in @Silveri's answer it requires the ICMP protocol, which [wasn't implemented in earlier versions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/18#issuecomment-207663429).

As of build 14352, it became [enabled for consoles which have administrator privileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14352).

As of build 14926, it became [enabled for consoles which do not have administrator privileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14926).