# How to access Linux subsystem from same local network?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I create a Node server on Linux subsystem, it can access by localhost in windows, and its' local IP is 192.168.0.17. However, it cannot be accessed by other PC in the same local network by typing 192.168.0.17.

Comment: Have you configured the Node server to be accessible on anything other then localhost?  Have you follow the appropriate documentation to do that? Most server services by default are not accessible by anything other then localhost in most cases.

Comment: Be sure the WSL DNS instance is configured correctly: https://superuser.com/questions/1066272/internet-access-not-working-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I turn on the windows firewall and it blocks all the income request. After I set up the rules of the firewall. It works correctly.