# Update/Upgrade Debian in Windows Linux Subsystem: Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'

Tags: windows-10, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

Linux Subsystems does not resolve names, so it is impossible to install or update anything, why does it happen and how can it be fixed?

[image]

```
ecker@Lame_Slug:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

Windows 10 Pro x64 1909 English

**Obs.:** Windows is fresh/new install and no edit was made in Debian...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following the question/answer analysis queue, when I came across a post by **[@Ben N](https://superuser.com/users/380318/ben-n)** in **[Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1066278/969781)** on the similar question **[Internet access not working in Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1066272/internet-access-not-working-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux)**.

1. Open Debian Type:

```bat
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
[type your password]+Enter
```

2. Add one name and the DNS Server IP address:

```bat
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

3. Use **<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>** and **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>** to write, and **<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>** to exit.
4. Run your commands, in my case:

```bat
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo apt-get install xfce4
sudo apt-get install lxde
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
```

[image]

A line added to the file made it work, where the final intention was to follow this tutorial that shows how to access a **[Debian (with Xfce or LXDE Desktop) Linux station via Windows Remote Desktop](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5255423/Linux-on-Windows)**.

[image]

[image]